# How to manage clickable of an item?

Tags: android

Guys I generated a card programmatically and also there are four imageview but I can't control when I clicked them.Because of I used lparams, I cannot use **setOnClickListener()** .I mean, I just want to do something when I click it, card or any component.How can I do it?

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
     android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
     android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton" />
```

and here card

```
final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT,MATCH_PARENT);
final CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
cardView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
imagView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            relativeLayout.addView(cardView);
        }
    });
```

this is adding card but I want to click that card and do something like giving a message with toast or etc.

Comment: please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

First. Set **id** for card(to identify that card):

```
cardView.setId(777);
```

Second. set click listenter:

```
cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Finally:

```
public void onClick(View v){
   if(v.getId() == 777){
        //Ta daaaaaam
   }
}
```

Comment: but for more card?Is program can give id automatically?

Comment: @Mus if program give id, how U can to know which id for which card program was give? Of curse you skip this step, just set click listener, it's not require

Answer (score 0):

You doing good job. But you miss one moment. You doesnt set `clickListener()` to the `cardView`. So what u need to do:

```
final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT,MATCH_PARENT);
final CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
cardView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Show toast or something...
        }
    }
);
imagView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            relativeLayout.addView(cardView);
        }
    }
);
```